# Swapping hard drives without RAID

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I currently have 3 hard drives on my computer:

- 64GB SSD for OS
- 1TB HDD for Data
- 250GB HDD for Programs

I currently only have around 20GB left on my Programs HDD and am planning on getting a larger one. Is it possible to transfer every file from my Programs HDD on to the new hard drive, change the drive letter of the new hard drive to match the old one, and have everything check out ok in the windows registry so that the only difference in using my computer would be the additional space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically: yes, that would be possible. But it might not be as straightforwards as you like since you will not just have to copy the programs but also ACLs (permissions).

Tho easy ways to do this would be:

- Connect the new harddisk and format it if needed.
- Copy all programs from the 250GB HDD to the new drive.
- Optionally: remove the old 250GB HDD (your choice, but if you get a new 2-3TB drive then the relative storage space is trivial, while noise production and power use is not).
- Go to drive management and change drive letters.

or:

- Make a full disk image of the 250GB HDD. Use CloneZilla or something similar.
- Connect the new harddisk (optionally remove the old drive)
- Restore the image to the new HDD, which will keep all data including access controll lists, ownership of files etc etc.